# Configuration of a Cisco IP Phone 7916 and 7975g

Tags: cisco, voip, asterisk, sip, expansion

**Hi everyone**,
I would appreciate some help configuring my Cisco IP Phone 7975.
In fact the phone works well with the SIP firmware (**version SIP75.8-4-1ES2**) and an Asterisk Server. Now I would like to connect a Cisco IP Phone 7916 Expansion Module to it. The problem is during my search on the web I have only found explanations to configure the expansion with a Cisco Unified Call Manager but not with Asterisk.

For information, the IP Phone gets its configuration file from a tftp server and the file follows the SEP.cnf.xml format.

So if someone here have already done this task before, can he pleases explain me.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Alex

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had very much success with these phones and Asterisk in SIP mode.  However, they work well using SCCP.  Take a look at this [SCCP module for Asterisk](http://sourceforge.net/projects/chan-sccp-b/).

Answer (score 0):

I just configured a 7016 module successfully. You need the firmware for the add-on module and then in the SEP.cnf.xml file, you add this after the  tag:

```
<addOnModules>
<addOnModule idx="1">
<loadInformation>B016-1-0-4-2"</loadInformation>
</addOnModule>
</addOnModules>
```

Then, in the `<sipLines>` node, you add entries such as this one for the keys you want to configure:

```
<line button="9">
<featureID>21</featureID>
<featureLabel>Joe Bloggs</featureLabel>
<speedDialNumber>4000</speedDialNumber>
<featureOptionMask>1</featureOptionMask>
</line>
```

Then, update your device with this configuration file and firmware using the TFTP process and it should work out fine.

Hope this works for you!